# How to simplify an expression multiplied by infinity?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions

I am taking a limit which yields an expression of variables multiplied by `-∞`. Shouldn't this simplify to just infinity? I've tried adding assumptions that the variables are positive and real, but that didn't help.

```
Limit[
  exx, x -> L, 
  Direction -> "FromBelow", 
  Assumptions -> 
    {L > 0 && ubar1 > 0 && ubar2 > 0 && ubar3 > 0 && 
       ubar1 ∈ Reals && ubar2 ∈ Reals && ubar3 ∈ Reals}]]
```

> ```
> (ubar1 + 3 ubar2 - 4 ubar3) (-∞)
> ```

Here's my full code:

```
ClearAll[Evaluate[Context[] <> "*"]];

(* givens *)
Ne1 = -1/2 ξ (1 - ξ);
Ne2 = 1/2 ξ (1 + ξ);
Ne3 = 1 - ξ^2;

xbar1 = 0;
xbar2 = L;
xbar3 = 1/2 L + α*L;
(* solving for xbar from the isoparametric definition of a straight 3 bar element *)
{{xbar}, {nubar}} = 
  {{xbar1, xbar2, xbar3}, {ubar1, ubar2, ubar3}}.{{Ne1}, {Ne2}, {Ne3}};

(* Get the Jacobian J = dxbar/dξ *)
J = D[xbar, ξ];
J = Simplify[J];

(* Set the Jacobian equal to zero (to find minima) and rearrange for ξ *)
Print["J = ", J, " = 0 is minimized where ", Reduce[J == 0, ξ]];

Print["Examining ", Reduce[J == 0, ξ][[1]][[2]], 
  ", the values of α which minimize the function occur at ±(1/4)"];

Print["Now to determine the axial strain"];

α = 1/4;

Print["Letting α = 0.25 and rearranging the equation for xbar to solve for ξ, we get ", 

Simplify[Reduce[x == xbar, ξ][[2, 2, 2]]]];

ξ = 1 + (2 Sqrt[L (L - x)])/L;

(* The strain is found *)
u = Ne1*ubar1 + Ne2*ubar2 + Ne3*ubar3;
exx = D[u, x];

Print[
  "As we approach the endpoint, x -> L, and the strain ", Subscript[ϵ, xx], " -> ", 
  Limit[exx, x -> L, Direction -> "FromBelow", Assumptions -> L > 0], " ≡ ∞ "];
```

Comment: To fully understand what is happening in your code, we will need the definition of `ex`. Please add that definition to your question by editing this post (do not give as comment).

Comment: Also, it seems to me that, since it is impossible under your assumptions, to know whether `(ubar1 + 3 ubar2 - 4 ubar3)` is positive or negative, the result you are getting can not be further simplified.

Comment: @m_goldberg I added the whole code